# Speed up Keras Model Prediction Load Times

Tags: keras, prediction, api

I am trying to create a prediction API using keras which loads the model predicts and closes the model. But initializing time in python is about 3-5 secs so each request takes around 5 secs to return the prediction irrespective of number inputs rows(predictions)

Is there any way to keep the model loaded and then stream the input data to get prediction. Like a Pre loaded model either through a socket or a port.

Similar to open office document converter

```
\program\soffice.exe -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -headless -nofirststartwizard -nologo
```

Keras Prediction Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import sys
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
X = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]).values
prediction = model.predict(X)
pd.DataFrame(prediction).to_json(sys.argv[2])
```

Script is called as

```
python3.6 predict.py input_scaled.csv output_scaled.json
```

The prediction time are as follows

```
#row    time
1       4.76 secs
10      4.49 secs
50      5.37 secs
5000    5.46 secs
50000   12.7 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to work like this without flask or django. Just using default http.server in python

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging
import sys
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import load_model
from urllib.parse import urlparse
model = load_model('model.h5')

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        query = urlparse(self.path).query
        params = dict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("&"))
        X = pd.read_csv(params["input"]).values
        prediction = model.predict(X)
        pd.DataFrame(prediction).to_json(params["output"])
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("Processed".encode('utf-8'))

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8080):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Trigger Server using

```
python3.6 predict_server.py 8000
```

API like

```
http://ip/localhost:8000/?input=predict_scaled.csv&output=prediction.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to create a flask app that will load the model once and have and endpoint where you can send your data as requests to your already loaded model.

A rough skeleton of the service would look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return ''

@app.route('/predict/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    X = pd.read_csv(request.get_data()).values
    prediction = model.predict(X)
    return pd.DataFrame(prediction).to_json()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    app.run()
```

Then you could make an HTTP request to `localhost:5000/predict`, via another script and it would return your predictions, which then you could save or do whatever you want.

Comment: I do not use flask, but how do we know that the model in the `predict` controller is loaded only once during the lifecycle of the app (and not for example like php does loads it every time anew)?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to show where the model is loaded. This happens once, and remains loaded as long as the server is running. Every time a request is sent to the `/predict` endpoint, the model makes a prediction.